# Checkbox deshabilitar, luego de que se ponga en checked

Tags: javascript, php

La idea es que al hacer clic en el checkbox, se ponga en estado checked y luego de ahí, no se pueda quitar el checked. El tema es que tengo utilizado el disable para otro "método". Explico:

Los estados del checkbox que designe: checked (Entregado), (Sin_entregado) y disable (No_disponible)
La tabla trae los datos de la BD y los checkbox aparecen como Sin_entregado, el cliente al darle clic y lo pone en Entregado, y hace un update en la fila de la BD.  La idea es que no le quiten el Entregado una vez hecho este paso.

inputs:

```
            <td><?=$row[0]?></td>
            <td><?=$row[1]?></td>
            <td><?=$row[2]?></td>
            <td><?=str_ireplace($serv_regular, $serv_nueva, $row[3])?></td>
            <td class="datos-td"><?=str_ireplace($desc_regular, $desc_nuevo, $row[4])?></td>
            <td><?=$row[5];?></td>
            <td>
            <input type="hidden" class="id-datos" name="habilitar" value="<?php echo $row[6] ? 
             >">
            <?php if ($row[7] == 1): ?>
            <input class="habilitar task-chk" data-id="<?=$row[6]?>" name="habilitar" 
            type="checkbox" checked >
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php if($row[7] == 0): ?>
            <?php if ($row[4] == "SE SOBREPASO EL MAXIMO DE ACCESOS"): ?>
            <input type="checkbox" class="habilitar task-chk" name="habilitar" disabled>
            <?php else: ?>
            <input type="checkbox" class="habilitar task-chk" data-id="<?=$row[6]?>" 
             name="habilitar">
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
```

No sé si este tema que quiero hacer, es con PHP o JS, si alguien pudiera guiarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En un input cuando colocas `onclick="return false"` cancelas toda acción sobre él, puedes usar esto para lograr lo que buscas

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return this.checked">
```

Comment: excelente genio, era muy sencillo... Y yo buscando muchas formas por JS .. Gracias!